# How to set permissions for user to smb mount with fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab

Here is the line in my fstab file (with the names of the server and username changed):

```
//server/user /mnt/share cifs user=user,uid=1000,gid=1000,domain=DOMAIN,rw,username=user,password=password,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,_netdev 0 0
```

When this mounts the folder (which i created by the user and chown the user as the owner) has these properties:

```
dr----x--t. 2 user root       0 Jul  9 08:48 share
```

When I try to cd into the director as the user I get a `Permission Denied` error.  How can I make this work?

Comment: What is the server running?

Comment: It's a samba share.  I ended up getting ssh fs working instead as I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Guess what the [mount.cifs](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) man page says?
"file_mode=arg
If the server does not support the CIFS Unix extensions this overrides the default file mode".
I suggest you turn off the Unix extensions on your Samba server and try again. Edit [`smb.conf`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) and turn off [`unix extensions`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS), for example by adding `unix extensions = no` (the default is yes).